# JavaScript alternative for Chrome, regarding window.parent

Tags: javascript, silverlight, google-chrome

The following code is executed from a Silverlight application, which is running in an iframe, which is in a .aspx file:

```
    private void PostMessage<T>(Message<T> message)
    {
        HtmlWindow window = HtmlPage.Window;
        ScriptObject postMessage = window.Eval("window.parent.postMessage") as ScriptObject;

        if (postMessage != null)
        {
            string jsonMessage = ToJsonString(message);
            string[] args = { jsonMessage, "*" };
            postMessage.InvokeSelf(args);
        }
    }
```

This works fine in IE, but not in Google Chrome. This has to do with the window.parent reference, Chrome returns undefined.
When the code is called in Chrome, it will crash: "Failed to invoke self";
the stacktrace starts with "at System.Windows.Browser.ScriptObject.InvokeSelf(Object[] args)"

Can anyone tell me how to rewrite this code to support Google Chrome too?

Comment: Don't quote me, but i think this works: `window.frameElement.ownerDocument.parentWindow`

Comment: Thanks for your post; I've tried it, but now the code fails with a "Eval failed"....

Comment: Adding <script type="text/javascript">
        var postMessage = window.parent.postMessage;
    </script>
to the .aspx file didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
window.frameElement.ownerDocument.parentWindow
```